# Cursor stuck in position using MATE on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, touchpad, mate

Every single time I log into the MATE Desktop, the cursor is always stuck in a position, and I can't move it. Pulling up a terminal with ctrl+alt+t and typing in `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and `sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps` seem to solve the problem temporarily, but I need a permanent fix to this issue.

And the strange thing about this is this only happens on the MATE desktop. When I log into the XFCE desktop, it doesn't do this at all.

I love the MATE desktop, and I'm looking forward to getting this issue fixed.

System Specs If Needed:

Sony VAIO VPCEB35FX

Xubuntu 22.04

Comment: It may help if you're specific as to how you installed the MATE desktop to what I understand is a multi-desktop Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system. My thinking is you may not have installed all required components of Ubuntu-MATE thus unusual behavior (ps: I too *bloat* my system with multiple desktops; and how installed does matter in my experience; with differences on release)

Comment: I installed it via terminal. I used sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop . When I first installed it, it was working without a hitch. Then, as time went on, the problem started to occur.

Comment: Okay. I may have potentially stumbled upon a permanent fix for the issue. I ran `sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and then I ran `sudo apt install libinput-dev` and when I rebooted and logged into MATE desktop, the issue seems to be gone.